# Codes used in Mantis bug database

Tags: mantis

I am assuming these are the descriptions for the codes in the `mantis_bug_table` in the Mantis bug database.How can i confirm these descriptions ?

```
#Status ? Is it --> 10-New, 20-Acknowledged, 30-Confirmed, 40-Assigned,50-Resolved,60-Closed
#Severity ? Is it --> 10-FEATURE, 20-TRIVIAL, 30-TEXT, 40-TWEAK, 50-MINOR, 60-MAJOR, 70-CRASH, 80-BLOCK
#Priority ? Is it --> Urgent = 1, Not Urgent = 5, Disable = 0 . Default is 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are defined in **config_defaults_inc.php** and can be customized based on your requirements. Check the **MantisBT Enum Strings** in the above file.